# sql table using sum

Tags: sql

I would like a result of

```
ID       received       total
2          25            25
```

from   ItemReceived table

```
ID        item       received
2          1             5  
2          2             2
2          1             10
2          2             8
```

and ItemsToReceive table

```
ID        item       quantity
2           1            15
2           2            10
```

Is there a way to get this result?
I used this code:

```
SELECT sum(ItemsToReceive.quantity), SUM( ItemReceived.received) 
FROM ItemsToReceive 
INNER JOIN ItemReceived ON ItemReceived.ID = ItemsToReceive.ID
GROUP BY poitems.poid
```

I got a wrong result making received to 50...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to be a little clearer with your question. Post tables of your data, we have no idea what your joins are joining to

Comment: Are you really supposed to join those two tables? Try `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: sorry for the messy table. its my first time to post question though. i just want to get a record a total of quantity and received group by ID.

Comment: a sum of quantity and a sum of received group by ID

Comment: i use union all and i get received and total in one column. which is not the result i want to get

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t1.Id,t1.quantity, t2.received from
(
    SELECT ID,sum(quantity) quantity from ItemsToReceive group by id
) as t1 inner join
(
    SELECT ID,SUM(received) as received from ItemReceived group by id
) as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
   ;WITH quantity AS ( 
                    SELECT sum(ItemsToReceive.quantity) As TotQuant 
                    ,ItemsToReceive.id AS id
                    FROM ItemsToReceive 
                    GROUP BY ItemsToReceive.id
    ), Prod As (
                    SELECT SUM( ItemReceived.received) As TotRec
                    ,ItemReceived.ID As Id
                    FROM ItemReceived 
                    GROUP BY ItemReceived.ID 
    )
    SELECT 
     q.Id
    ,p.TotRec As Received
    ,q.TotQuant As Quantity
    FROM quantity q
    INNER JOIN Prod p on p.Id = q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID , sum(received) , sum(quantity) from ItemReceived left join ItemsToReceive on (ItemReceived.ID = ItemsToReceive.ID and ItemReceived.item = ItemsToReceive.item) group by ID
```